# In JavaScript, how do I assign the collected form field values to an new Object

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have searched multiple websites for assistance, but I still can not find out how to assign the collected form field values to a new Object.

Here is the HTML FILE

```js
function getData() {
  let a = document.querySelector('firstName').value;
  let b = document.querySelector('lastName').value;
  let c = document.querySelector('emailAddress').value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>HTML5 Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br><br>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br><br>
    <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="getData()" name="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you want this _object_ to look like?

Comment: I would say use `getElementById` instead of `querySelector` as the latter can result in issues later.

Comment: @Manish Any reason you suggested that - what issues can arise by doing querySelector  method ? I will be happy to know.

Comment: Your query selector strings are incorrect. If you're trying to get the elements by ID, you want `document.querySelector('#firstName')`, etc

Comment: @Manish: `querySelector` is fine, and is even reasonable to use it as a general replacement for the historical DOM selection methods.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping  The reason i suggested avoiding querySelector is that querySelector is a generic kind of method that mean you can use it with variety of queries to get the elements while getElementByDI is specific. One returns an array while the other returns an object. And thirdly there are performance differences when the DOM starts growing. Since id's are there in the above code i recommended. But it always is a matter of perspective and in my opinion getElementById is slightly better.

Comment: @Manish `querySelector` only ever returns one element or null. You might be thinking of`querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 2):

I'd just go with a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance to collect all the field data and then convert that to an object via [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
// Find the form and attach a "submit" event listener
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {

  // prevent the default "submit" action
  e.preventDefault() 
  
  // create a FormData instance to capture all fields
  const data = new FormData(e.target)
  
  // convert to an object
  const obj = Object.fromEntries(data)
  
  // display the results
  console.log(obj)
})
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br><br>
  <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br><br>
  <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```